# QML XmlListModel returns 0 with nested tags

Tags: xml, qt, qml

I have multiple XML URLs which I want to parse and use the provided data for my frond-ent application.

I already got it working for this XML file:

```
<Categories>
  <Category Name="CA" CategoryID="1"/>
  <Category Name="CB" CategoryID="2"/>
  <Category Name="CC" CategoryID="3"/>
</Categories>
```

Working [QML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML) code for this one:

```
XmlListModel {
    id : categories

    source : xmlURL;

    query: "/Categories/Category"

    XmlRole { name: "id"; query: "string(@CategoryID)" }
    XmlRole { name: "name"; query: "string(@Name)" }
}
```

Now I tried the same with this one:

```
<Gastros>
  <Gastro GastroID="1" CreatedBy="528">
    <Tag1>100</Tag1>
    <Tag2>100</Tag2>
  </Gastro>
  <Gastro GastroID="2" CreatedBy="333">
    <Tag1>100</Tag1>
    <Tag2>100</Tag2>
  </Gastro>
</Gastros>
```

And this is my QML code:

```
XmlListModel {
    id : gastronomyList

    source : xmlURL

    query: "/Gastros/Gastro"

    onStatusChanged : {
        console.log("Status GastroList: " + status);
        if (status === XmlListModel.Ready) {
            console.log("GastroList: " + count);

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                console.log(get(i).id);
                console.log(get(i).createdBy);
            }
        }
    }

    XmlRole { name: "id"; query: "string(@GastroID)" }
    XmlRole { name: "createdBy"; query: "string(@CreatedBy)" }
}
```

In this case count is always 0.

For the first step I want to get all Elements (in this example 2) back and just print the IDs in the console...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

When viewing the page content (right click → *Inspect Element*) in the inspector tab, the Gastro tag looks as follows:

```
<Gastro xmlns="urn:schemas-etourist:Gastro">
```

This is used for my namespace (I already suspected it had to do something with the namespace):

```
namespaceDeclarations: "declare default element namespace \"urn:schemas-etourist:Gastro\";"
```

Now I get all my Elements :)